# Irrlicht error "No Entry point"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, irrlicht

I have done some project in Irrlicht and it compiles all well, however when I try to run it, it gives me following error

```
The procedure entry point ?IdenttityMatrix@core@irr@@3V?$CMatrix4@M@12@B 
could not be located in the dynamic link library Irrlicht.dll.
```

What am I missing here, 'cause I can't figure out what exactly it is complaining about.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two dlls, which one did you use (which path)?

Comment: I'm using the one from my ROOT System directory, I didn't specify anything in my VS10 to be used some other. Actually I have used static lib .lib file, and that may be the cause of the disruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least your application starts! This means that your application links dynamically to Irrlicht.dll and not statically (in the later case, your application would not even start). This failure indicates that the Irrlicht.dll library has successfully been **found** but that the entry point of the expected function (in your case IdenttityMatrix) has not been found. Most probably, you are not using the right version of the library.

Comment: I see, so I will have to provide new .dll file where is IdentityMatrix available! Let me check it and see what happens. :)

Comment: I have included .lib file, but when I don't include it, it gives me following error Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class irr::core::CMatrix4<float> const irr::core::IdentityMatrix" (__imp_?IdentityMatrix@core@irr@@3V?$CMatrix4@M@12@B) C:\Users\JCS\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\

Comment: you must of course take care to provide the lib (for the linker) that fits to the dll (for the loader).

Comment: Aha, so it must be diff version of dll and lib file that causes this issue, will try to download newest versions of dll and lib for Irrlicht.